# How to get values from HTML form

Tags: php, html

I have the files **Page.php** and **Insert.php**:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span contenteditable style='border:1px solid#000;display:block;width:99'></span>
    <select><option style=display:none>Select</option><option>Yes</option><option>No</option></select>
    <form action=Insert.php>
      <input type=submit>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
  $c=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database name');
  $DATETIME="2017-01-16 14:54:06";
  $span="Text inserted.";
  $select="No";
  mysqli_query($c,"insert into`table name`(`column 1 name`,`column 2 name`,`column 3 name`)values('$DATETIME','$span','$select')");
?>
```

How can I make the variables `$DATETIME`, `$span` and `$select` be equal to: the current date (example: 2017-01-16 14:54:06), the `<span>`'s content (example: Text inserted.) and the selected option from the element `<select>` (example: Yes)?

I'm using XAMPP and PhPMyAdmin.

Comment: So basically you're asking how to get your values from a form

Comment: @YourCommonSense Your profile pic is so relevant it's freaky.

Comment: do not use a span to get user input in a form, use `<input type="text">` instead.

Comment: and the answer can be found in any php beginners guide

Comment: @YourCommonSense - I'm asking how to get my values from 276 `<span>`s and 67 `<select>`s.

Comment: @roberto06 - Please comment about the question.

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ - I have to use `<span>`.

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ - Where?

Comment: you *have to* use span ? hmmm ok well but if you use a non form element, you still have to add a hidden input to be able to send it to the server and ass a javascript function to sync the content of the span and the input. For the *where ?* question, i would say : just use Google

Comment: @C̲̅R̲̅O̲̅Z̲̅E̲̅T̲̅ - Only form elements can send information to the databases? Why? Also: "ass" xD

Comment: No, you could do this also with JavaScript for example, but it's just the simplest way to do so with a `<form>`-Tag. Look up my answer and feedback my if that works :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above your select is outside of your form element, so to start that should be fixed. Conventionally you would also supply a form method (it defaults to get, but IMO is clearer if you specify).

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span contenteditable style='border:1px solid#000;display:block;width:99'></span>

    <form action=Insert.php method="post">
        <select>
            <option style=display:none>Select</option>
            <option>Yes</option><option>No</option>
        </select>
        <input type=submit>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you would need to get that data from the $_POST array and filter it. In your code example you are using dummy variables instead of anything from the form so for the next portion I'll just duplicate that.

```
<?php
  // DB connect
  $c=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database name');

  // Dummy vars
  $DATETIME="2017-01-16 14:54:06";
  $span="Text inserted.";
  $select="No";

  // Query String examples (extra format for readability)
  $query1 = "insert into`table name`(
        `column 1 name`,
        `column 2 name`,
        `column 3 name`
      ) values (
        '". $DATETIME ."',
        '". $span ."', 
        '". $select ."'
      )";

  $query2 = "insert into`table name`(
        `column 1 name`,
        `column 2 name`,
        `column 3 name`
      ) values (
        '{$DATETIME}',
        '{$span}', 
        '{$select}'
      )";

  // Run Query
  mysqli_query($c, $query);
?>
```

The two query string examples use 1) concatenation, 2) interpolation. Use whichever one seems easier to read for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem, you could check out [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) link for a basic example.

Anyways, here's your solution:

Firstly,you have to restructure your HTML. You have to place all relevant fields of your form in the form tag like this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="insert.php">
            // Here all your input, select, textarea etc. fields
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Next, you can't submit a `<span>`'s value in a form. Use `<input>`-elements instead:

```
<input type="text" />
```

Or check out JavaScript (-> [XHR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)), which you could workaround this problem with.

Then, you have to set the `name`-Attribute in all the fields you want to be submitted:

```
<input type="text" name="myTextField" />
<select name="mySelect">
    ...
</select>
```

When you implement this code, you can use your values in `insert.php` like this:

```
$text = $_POST['myTextField'];
$select = $_POST['mySelect'];
```

Tip: Use `echo "<pre>".var_dump($_POST)."</pre>";` in you PHP-File to check the values you got form the form.

The current time can easily be gotten in PHP with [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php):

```
$datetime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
```

**Note:**
If you continue with this project and consider going live with this, please read first [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp) article, which tells you the basics of security issues of your site and additionally [this](http://bobby-tables.com/) article about dangerous SQL-Injections.